# book[] in if statement error

Tags: c, function, if-statement, struct

```
void displayInventory(const struct Book book[], const int size) {
```

Idk y book[] getting an error in visual studio plz help.

```
if (book[] < 0) {
    printf("The inventory is empty!");
    printf("===================================================");
}
else {
    printf("Inventory\n");
    printf("===================================================\n");
    printf("ISBN      Title               Year Price  Quantity\n");
    printf("---------+-------------------+----+-------+--------");
    printf("%-10.0d%-20s%-5d$%-8.2f%-8d", book[]._isbn, book[]._title, book[]._year, book[]._price, book[]._qty);
}
}
```

Comment: you must specify book[some_index] value to check..

Comment: You can only use the empty `[]` in a variable definition (typically in a function parameter list; there are some other related contexts where it can appear).  In a reference such as `if (book[booknumber].isbn < 0)`, you must provide a subscript (I used `booknumber` here; I probably would use a shorter name in a program).

Comment: Also note that you should not create names that start with an underscore.  If you know enough that you don't need to ask this question, you might be able to quote the exact rule, but while you need to ask such questions, the rule is simple: do not start names you create with an underscore — despite any precedents you see.  Most such names are reserved for the implementation.  You may not run into problems immediately, but it may come back and hurt you later.

Comment: thats how the teacher wants it, but yeah i understand now, thx for helping

Comment: what do you expect this line: `(book[] < 0) ` to evaluate to?   Remember that  `book[]` is a pointer.   Pointers are unsigned (in most instances) so the expression is saying:  'is this pointer less than 0'  Probably not what you want to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `book` variable is an *array* of `Struct Book` items. If you want to access *one* of those items, you need to provide the index of it, such as with:

```
if (book[0].id == 7) ...
```

In your case (checking the inventory), you probably wanted to use the passed-in size (assuming that's the number of items in use rather than the size of the array - that's probably what it should be in this case since there's no need for an inventory lister to know the size of the actual array itself, just the number of items you want to show):

```
if (size <= 0) // inventory is empty.
```

Putting together *both* of those items, you'll probably end up with something along the lines of:

```
void displayInventory (const struct Book book[], const int size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        puts ("The inventory is empty!");
        puts ("======================================================");
        return;
    }
    puts ("Inventory");
    puts ("=======================================================");
    puts ("ISBN       Title                Year  Price    Quantity");
    puts ("----------+--------------------+-----+--------+--------");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
        printf ("%-10.0d %-20s %-5d$ %-8.2f %-8d\n",
            book[idx]._isbn, book[idx]._title, book[idx]._year,
            book[idx]._price, book[idx]._qty);
    }
}
```